# Looking for a 1TB/2TB drive that will work with Both Windows and Ubuntu 10.10 / 10.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I just bought a new laptop with 500 GB disk space. I plan to install Windows as well as Ubuntu 10.10 and others on it. While 500GB is a decent size for a disk, media now days takes up a lot of room. I want to buy an external, USB-powered mini-hard drive, but I want to make sure that it will work with both operating systems. I am looking for at least 1TB capacity. Can you recommend one?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): `it is not about` **a shopping or buying recommendation**

Comment: Although I see this as a shopping or buying recommendation in the way it is currently worded, you might want to reword your question to ask if USB-powered mini-hard drives are compatible with both Windows [insert version here] and Ubuntu 10.10 / 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

In any event, a portable hard drive formatted to the NTFS file system will be compatible between both operating systems (NTFS read/write support is enabled by default in 10.10).